# android studio Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I imported an existing project to my android studio, everthing seems to be ok, but when i try to run the code using a data-cable and an android phone i get this error message repeated many times:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try multidex

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 15 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 25

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true       //You have already did this 
         }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'   // add this in  dependencies
}
```

Also you can try clean project and rebuild your project i hope resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to include in build.gradle(Module:app) Section:

```
android {

defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and check if you haven't done any refactoring before breaking your codes.  Sometimes, renaming a package or java class could cause the error
        *Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes*

Rename your files back to previous name if you did refactor any package or java class